# Why does code stop executing at a certain line?

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, c++-cli

I have the following code:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Form1 ^ form = gcnew Form1;
    form->ShowDialog();

    //Starts the .jar file
    ServerProcess *aServer = new ServerProcess();
    aServer->NewServer();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the programs opens the window (`Form1 ^ form = gcnew Form1; form->ShowDialog();`), but it will not run the other lines of code until I close the form.

**Why does this happen? How can I fix this?**

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to "Cheers and hth. -Alf" I now know that due to `ShowDialog()` any code after it won't be executed until I close the form. `Application::Run(gcnew Form1())` results in the same behavior.

Comment: how about, u now, reading the documentation of, like, `ShowDialog`

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Oh, I understand now. Thank you. The same thing happened for `Application::Run(gcnew Form1());`. What else could I use to launch the form, but so that the rest of the code is executed before the form is closed?

Comment: you can possily move the "Starts the .jar file" code to a point before running the dialog. it depends on what `NewServer` does. if it blocks, then you might spin off a thread that does it (whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) says:

> You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your
>   application. When this method is called, the code following it is not
>   executed until after the dialog box is closed.

If you just want the code to continue on instead of blocking until the popup is closed consider using [Form.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx) instead of [Form.ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx).

Comment: Nope, sadly, `Application::Run(gcnew Form1());` results in the same behavior as `Form1 ^ form = gcnew Form1; form->ShowDialog();`.

Answer (score 0):

"When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed. " You need to call ShowDialog in another thread if you don't want it to block your following code.